# How to configure and load spring context in servlet project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am pretty new to spring. I have dynamic web application project. Inside i have a servlet which is receive request. The request comes with a request no. Based on the no i will create a new object for appropriate request class and serve the request. Now i need to integrate with spring. i applied the below configuration,

WEB.XML (To load spring context)

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/docspring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In servlet

```
package com.receve;
@Controller
@WebServlet("/Recever")
public class Recever extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private ClassOne one;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

     //request parameters receved and
     if(req==1){
       one.print();
     }
}

    public ClassOne getOne() {
        return One;
    }

    public void setOne(ClassOne one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

}
```

In ClassOne

```
package com.operations;
@Component
public Class ClassOne{
  public void print(){
   //some statement;
  }
}
```

In spring.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
```

But while running the application i am getting NullPointerexception while calling one.print() method. what is the proper way(configuration) to obtain this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you want. a servlet or a controller. Currently it is both and you have 2 instances of that class. I suggest you remove the `@WebServler` annotation and `extends Servlet` and make it a proper controller using `@RequestMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `extends HttpServlet`  and  Autowiring is turned off by default, so the default autowiring mode for a bean is 'no'.